# Loading/reading a .txt file

Tags: java, file, filereader

My last assignment in my intro to Java class asked us to:

1. Write a console-based (AKA command line based) menu for your user to interact with.
2. Include the following commands in the menu (you must write code for each):

   3. Input a list of students, use the menu from ArrayDemo: Display, Add, Remove, etc.
   4. Save the list of students to a file using a filename provided by your user
   5. Load the list of students from a file using a filename provided by your user.

I have already done 1-3. How can I get my program to load the info in a .txt file? (Honestly I am not sure if this is what my teacher means when he says loading, because i feel like this may be a bit more complicated than what we have gone over)

I have been able to get my program to open the .txt file with Notepad but I have no idea how to get it to read the whole file and/or save the text info into my program.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.*;

public class ArrayDemo_File {
    private static Student[]   StudentList = new Student[10];
    private static FileWriter  file;
    private static PrintWriter output;
    private static FileReader fr;

    public static void StudentIndex() {
        int index = 0;

        while (index < StudentList.length) {
            if(StudentList[index] != null) {
                System.out.println(index + ": " + StudentList[index].getLName() + ", " 
                    + StudentList[index].getFName());
            }
            else {
                return;
            }

            index++;
        }
    }

    // View detailed data for Students listed in the index
    public static void IndexData() {
        int index = 0;

        while (index < StudentList.length) {
            if(StudentList[index] !=null) {
                System.out.println(index + ": " + StudentList[index].getLName() + ", " + StudentList[index].getFName());
                System.out.println("A Number: \t" + StudentList[index].getANum());
                System.out.println("Address: \t" + StudentList[index].getAddress());
                System.out.println();
            }
            else {
                return;
            }

            index++;
        }
    }

    // ADD STUDENT
    public static void AddStudent() throws IOException {
        // Memory
        Student student = new Student();
        Address address = new Address();
        Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);

        String last;
        String frst;
        int num;

        int house;
        String Street;
        String City;
        String State;
        int Zip;
        String Line2;

        // Student Name and ID
        System.out.println();
        System.out.print("Last Name:\t");
        last = kb.nextLine();

        System.out.println();
        System.out.print("First Name:\t");
        frst = kb.nextLine();

        System.out.println();
        System.out.print("A Number:\tA");
        num = kb.nextInt();

        //Address
        System.out.println();
        System.out.print("What is your house number?\t");
        house = kb.nextInt(); 
        kb.nextLine();

        System.out.println();
        System.out.print("What is your Street's name?\t");
        Street = kb.nextLine();

        System.out.println();
        System.out.print("What is your city?\t");
        City = kb.nextLine();

        System.out.println();
        System.out.print("What is your State?\t");
        State = kb.nextLine();

        System.out.println();
        System.out.print("What is your zip code?\t");
        Zip = kb.nextInt();

        kb.nextLine();

        System.out.println();
        System.out.print("Line 2: \t");
        Line2 = kb.nextLine();

        System.out.println("");

        // Processing
        address = new Address( house, Street, City, State, Zip, Line2 );
        student = new Student(last, frst, num, address);

        int index = 0;

        while( index < StudentList.length ) {
            if( StudentList[index] == null ) break;
            index++;
        }

        StudentList[index] = student;
    }

    // REMOVE STUDENT
    public static void RemoveStudent() {
        System.out.println("Remove student");

        int index = 0;

        while (index < StudentList.length) {
            if (StudentList[index] !=null) {
                System.out.println(index + ": " + StudentList[index].getLName() + " " +     StudentList[index].getFName());
            }
            index++;
        }

        Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);
        int response;

        System.out.println(" Please enter student number to remove or -1 to cancel removal");
        System.out.print("\nInput: ");

        response = Integer.parseInt(kb.nextLine());

        if (response != -1) {
            StudentList[response] = null;
        }

        Student[] StudentListTemp = new Student[10];
        int nulls = 0;
        for(int x = 0; x < StudentList.length; x++) {
            if (StudentList[x] == null) {
                nulls++;
            }
            else {
                StudentListTemp[x - nulls] = StudentList[x];
            }
        }

        StudentList = StudentListTemp;
    }


    public static void WriteFile() throws IOException {
        String fileName;
        Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Please enter a  name for your file: ");
        fileName = kb.nextLine();

        output = new PrintWriter(fileName + ".txt");

        for( int x = 0; x < StudentList.length; x++ ) {
            if( StudentList[x] == null )
                continue;

            output.println( "[" + x + "]" );
            output.println( StudentList[x].getFName()   );
            output.println( StudentList[x].getLName()   );
            output.println( StudentList[x].getAddress() );
        }

        output.close();

        System.out.println("\n\tFile saved successfully!");
    }

    public static void loadFile() throws IOException {
        Student student = new Student();
        String fileName;
        Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Please enter the name of the file: ");
        fileName = kb.nextLine();

        File file = new File(fileName + ".txt");
        if(!file.exists()) {
            System.err.println("\n\tError(404)): File Not Found!");
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("\n\tFile found! It will now open!");

            //FileReader fr = new FileReader(fileName + ".txt");
            //System.out.println(fr);
            ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("Notepad.exe", fileName + ".txt");
            pb.start();
        }
    }

    //CONSOLE MENU
    public static void Menu() throws IOException {
        Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);
        int response;
        boolean run = true;

        while(run) {
            System.out.println("--------------------------" );
            System.out.println("  OPTIONS:                 ");
            System.out.println(" 0) View Student Names     ");
            System.out.println(" 1) View Student details   ");
            System.out.println(" 2) Add Student            ");
            System.out.println(" 3) Remove Student         ");
            System.out.println(" 4) Save to File           ");
            System.out.println(" 5) Load File              ");
            System.out.println(" 6) Close Program          ");
            System.out.println("-------------------------- ");
            System.out.print(" Choose an option: ");

            response = Integer.parseInt(kb.nextLine());

            System.out.println();

            switch(response) {
                case 0:
                    StudentIndex();
                    break;
                case 1:
                    IndexData();
                    break;
                case 2:
                    AddStudent();
                    break;
                case 3:
                    RemoveStudent();
                    break;
                case 4:
                    WriteFile();
                    break;
                case 5:
                    loadFile();
                    break;
                case 6:
                    run = false;
                    break;
                default:
                    System.out.println(" ERROR: "+ response + " ! ");
            }
        }

        System.out.println( "Have a nice day!" );
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        // StudentList[0] = new Student("Doe", "Jon", 0000, new Address(00, "Road", "City", "State", 37343, "000"));
        // StudentList[1] = new Student("Ricketts", "Caleb", 0001, new Address(000, "000", "000", "0000", 000, "000"));
        // StudentList[2] = new Student("Smith", "Amanda", 2222, new Address(000, "000", "000", "000", 000, "000"));
        // StudentList[3] = new Student("Wilson", "Judy", 3333, new Address(000, "000", "000", "000", 000, "000"));

        Menu();
    }
}
```

I tried using the `filereader` to read the file but it doesn't output anything. Not sure what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Use these code you can write a text file in SDCard along with you need to set permission in android manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

before writing files also check whether your SDCard is Mounted & your external storage state is writable

```
Environment.getExternalStorageState()
```

Cod:

```
public void generateNoteOnSD(String sFileName, String sBody){
    try
    {
        File root = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "Notes");
        if (!root.exists()) {
            root.mkdirs();
        }
        File gpxfile = new File(root, sFileName);
        FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(gpxfile);
        writer.append(sBody);
        writer.flush();
        writer.close();
        Toast.makeText(this, "Saved", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    catch(IOException e)
    {
         e.printStackTrace();
         importError = e.getMessage();
         iError();
    }
   }
```

---

```
Check the http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html
```

Answer (score 0):

Scanner does a good job of reading .txt files.  Use another Scanner object to read through the file, one line at a time. After the code completes, each line of the file will be stored in list, with each line at the corresponding index (ex: list.get(0) will return the first line, list.get(1) the second, etc).

```
   public static void loadFile()
   {
      Student student = new Student();
      String fileName;
      Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);
      Scanner read;
      ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();

      System.out.println("Please enter the name of the file: ");
      fileName = kb.nextLine();

      File file = new File(fileName + ".txt");
      if(!file.exists())
      {
         System.err.println("\n\tError(404)): File Not Found!");

      } else {
         System.out.println("\n\tFile found! It will now open!");
         read = new Scanner(file);
         //FileReader fr = new FileReader(fileName + ".txt");
         //System.out.println(fr);
         //ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("Notepad.exe", fileName + ".txt");
         //pb.start();
         while(read.hasNextLine()) {
            String currentLine = read.nextLine();
            list.add(currentLine);
         }
      }

   }
```